# Why PHP Settings Check and Checking Component Dependency showing error during Magento 2.3 upgrade?

Tags: php, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.0, magento2.1.12

I was Upgrade Magento from 2.1.12 to 2.3 using Web Setup Wizard. During this process, **It show two error PHP Settings Check and Checking Component Dependency.**

We already set memory_limit=2GB in php/php.ini, But it show same error. 
Please Guide me.

Comment: Did you upgrade? @Lovely Setia

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution for memory limit

If you got composer memory allocation error try below way

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer install
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer update
```

If you got an error in setup to upgrade or static content deploy try below way

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```